# how to tell whether a cordova debug build is running

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to tell in javascript, whether the running code is a debug or release build.
This could facilitate constructs such as:

```
if (DEBUG) console.log("blah blah");
```

Comment: check these plugins https://github.com/ozexpert/cordova-plugin-device-meta and https://github.com/mattlewis92/cordova-plugin-is-debug

Comment: @Akis Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the cordova module `cordova-plugin-is-debug`.

To add the plugin:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-is-debug`

To find if in debug mode:

```
cordova.plugins.IsDebug.getIsDebug(function(isDebug) {
    console.log("blah blah");
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```